# Laravel show s3 image in blade template

Tags: laravel

I have an image stored in an S3 bucket that is linked to my Laravel app.  How can I display this image in a blade template?

So far I have...

```
<img src= "{{Image::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get('image/' . $filename))}}">
```

But this is not returning anything.

Does anybody have an example I can see?

Comment: If the S3 file is stored with public permissions, `<img src="{{ Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename) }}">` should do it.

Comment: It isn't stored with public permissions

Comment: I haven't tested it in a while, but I think `Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename)` will generate a short-lived URL to a private image (via a signed URL). Try it out. (Or store it with public permissions, as you apparently intend to use it publicly...)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.  Put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The S3 driver has a `url` function that'll get you a temporary, signed URL to the S3 object, so all you'll need to do is:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename) }}">
```